# How do I do a search call on one column of a table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to make a call on MySQL where I have a very big table. I'd like query to be able to search in one of there columns and find similar results. This is the sql query I have been trying:

```
SELECT gene FROM promoter where gene LIKE '%ccl5%' limit 10;
```

I included "limit 10" just to try it out. I have indexing on "gene" and it takes over 5-6 seconds for it to make this search. How can I search for a "phrase" in a specific coloumn with a least a decent speed?

I would also like to only get one of each result returned. If I search for 'ccl5' and it has been found several times, I get a list with all of 'ccl5' returned. I have tried using SELECT DISTINCT, but this causes the server to process the query for a long time.. I have yet to see it finish with this command.

Comment: Make sure `gene` is indexed that will help

Comment: As you can see in my description I have mentioned that I have indexing on 'gene'. But with indexing it takes about 6 seconds, which is way too long.

Comment: It looks like you have a database containing dna/gene sequences and you're storing this sequence as a string in a table field right now. It's very hard (or impossible) for MySQL to build a usuably index for searching an arbitrary element within this string. It may be more feasible to define the sequence in another table like `promoterid | genid | position`

Comment: Okay I will check that solution out. Can you tell me one thing though? When I search for "ccl" and I do get any "ccl5" returned using the query from my question. Can you tell me why this is?

Comment: Yeah I sorry about that, I did indeed miss that mention. Disregard my comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your values are really that big, you can try an [InnoDB fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html):

```
ALTER TABLE promoter add fulltext index index_name(gene);
```

Then select it like this:

```
SELECT gene FROM promoter WHERE match (gene ) against ('ccl5');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get an error that my table does not support full table indexing. I'm guessing it is because I'm using innoDB and not MyISAM. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: And before throwing in a FULLTEXT index at the very least have a read of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html to get a glimpse of some of the magic going on behind the scene here and whether it applies to your problem....

Comment: @Vanquiza since MySQL 5.6.4 you can add FULLTEXT indices to InnoDB tables too, as you can read in the link I provided.

Comment: Yes I gave it a read and figured it out, thank you very much :)